# Subclassing int leads to unexpected behavior

Tags: python

I'm trying to use a subclass for the int class to attach an additional label ("headline"). All works if I access the individual object, but if I collect several in a list, they all have the same property, while I would expect them to have the one I specified when creating the object.

I also tried with methods instead of properties to no further results.

I'm using Python 3.4.3.

```
import unittest

class LabeledInt(int):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls._headline = args[1]
        return super(LabeledInt, cls).__new__(cls, args[0])

    @property
    def headline(self):
        return self._headline

class SomeNumbers:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    @property
    def something(self):
        return LabeledInt(self.arg, "Something")

    @property
    def something_squared(self):
        return LabeledInt(self.arg ** 2, "Squared")

    @property
    def something_exponential(self):
        return LabeledInt(self.arg ** self.arg, "Exp.")

    def all_numbers(self):
        array = [
            LabeledInt(self.arg, "Something"),
            LabeledInt(self.arg ** 2, "Squared"),
            LabeledInt(self.arg ** self.arg, "Exp.")
        ]
        return array

S = SomeNumbers(2)


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, S.something)
        self.assertEqual("Something", S.something.headline)

    def test_something_squard(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, S.something_squared)
        self.assertEqual("Squared", S.something_squared.headline)

    def test_exp(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, S.something_exponential)
        self.assertEqual("Exp.", S.something_exponential.headline)

    def test_all_numbers_1(self):
        self.assertEqual(2, S.all_numbers()[0])

    def test_all_numbers_2(self):
        self.assertEqual("Something", S.all_numbers()[0].headline)

    def test_all_numbers_3(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, S.all_numbers()[1])

    def test_all_numbers_4(self):
        self.assertEqual("Squared", S.all_numbers()[1].headline)

    def test_all_numbers_5(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, S.all_numbers()[2])

    def test_all_numbers_6(self):
        self.assertEqual("Exp.", S.all_numbers()[2].headline)

for n in S.all_numbers():
    print(n.headline)
>>>
Exp.
Exp.
Exp.
```

Tests "test_all_numbers_2" und "...4" fail.

Why does this happen? And what's the best way around it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class LabeledInt(int):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls._headline = args[1]
#       ^^^
        return super(LabeledInt, cls).__new__(cls, args[0])
```

You are setting the attribute of the *class*, not of the *instance*. Try this:

```
class LabeledInt(int):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super(LabeledInt, cls).__new__(cls, args[0])
        self._headline = args[1]
#       ^^^^
        return self
```

---

**PS:** don't use `*args` and `**kwargs` if you are neither using them, nor passing them around. Also, Python 3's `super()` doesn't need arguments anymore. Consider using this code:

```
class LabeledInt(int):
    def __new__(cls, value, headline):
        self = super().__new__(cls, value)
        self._headline = headline
        return self
```